# PHP Pagination On limited number of records but not all

Tags: php, mysql

I need to select only 20 records from the table and than add pagination to show 5 records per page. i know there is a use of LIMIT in pagination, but first i need to get 20 records and than add pagination to those 20 records

Comment: you guys are misunderstanding the issue i am trying to describe. i don't want to know how to do the pagination. i know how to do the pagination. but i want to do pagination on last 20 records of the table. help me to understand how to achieve this rather than telling me how to do the pagination. thanks

Comment: So i guess your problem is fetching the last 20 records of the table correct? Check my updated answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could select 20 records at one time, and then use [array_slice](http://jp.php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) to do pagination.

***Edit:*** 
Why there are 2 LIMITS? The limit should be like:

```
1st page: LIMIT 0, 5
2nd page: LIMIT 5, 5
3rd page: LIMIT 10, 5
4th page: LIMIT 15, 5
```

Comment: i want to show last 20 most recent added books. and than want to show them 5 per page. so indeed there are 2 LIMITS. first limit to get 20 records and than add pagination to show 5 records per page. i just dont know how to achieve this. i dont want to use array slicing

Comment: @KhawerZeshan If you don't want use only one query, so what is your problem, shouldn't just be normal pagination use limit and offset?

Comment: Unsure about source of confusion @KhawerZeshan.

Answer (score 1):

I'll give you a basic idea of how to go about it.

1) Find out many many rows are there in your table (Simple -

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
In your case it is 20.
```

2) Find out how many pages you want to show based on how many rows per page you'd like to go for.

```
 intPages = ceil(intTotalRecords / 8 )
```

so all floating points will be ceil()ed meaning if this division produces the value 9.5, then 10 will be considered as the number of pages.

3) Find out the current page that you are on.
4) Find out the limit and offset (depending upon the page number) to be sent over to your query. Something on the following lines.

```
intLimit = 8;
intOffset = (intCurrentPage - 1) * intRowsPerPage;
```

5) Pull out the rows for the current page 
6) Display the info. (pagination links also by looping them over)

You need to check if the previous/next page goes past 1 or the max number of pages you are having and set the value of `intCurrentPage` accordingly.

**UPDATE** : To get the last 20 blocks of records from your table.

```
SELECT <column_names> FROM <table_name>
<optional_where_clause_goes_here>
ORDER BY <primary_autoincrement_id_field> DESC
LIMIT 20;
```

OR

```
SELECT <column_names> FROM <table_name>
WHERE <certain_conditions_here> 
and <primary_autoincrement_id_field> >= (select max(<primary_autoincrement_id_field>) from <table_name>) - 20
```

There's a dependency in each of the above queries I posted which is the field `<primary_autoincrement_id_field>` should be auto_increment.

Answer (score 0):

Use two queries. One to get the total count of records (it will return just one row, containing the count). After that use the LIMIT to select the pagination.

Answer (score 0):

first get total count from your table and call this function pagination it will return an array

```
 $array = pagination(200000);
```

and you can write query like

```
 $query = "SELECT * FROM your_table ".$array['querylimit'];
```

also you can use other array indexex for pagination.

```
function pagination($totalRows, $perPage = 20){
        $page = (isset($_POST['pagination']['page'])) ? intval($_POST['pagination']['page']) : 0;


        $perPage = intval($perPage);

        if($perPage == 0){
            $perPage = 20;
        }

        if(intval($page) < 0){
            $page = 1;
        }

        if (ceil($totalRows / $perPage) < intval($page)){
            $page = ceil($totalRows / $perPage);
        }

        if (!$page){
            $page = 1;
        }
        $prev = $page - 1;
        $next = $page + 1;


        if(intval($prev) < 0){
            $prev = 1;
        }


        $min = (($page - 1) * $perPage);

        if(ceil($totalRows / $perPage) < $next){
            $next = 0;
        }

        $end = $min+$perPage;
        if($end > $totalRows){
            $end = $totalRows;
        }
        $start = $min+1;
        $return['showing'] = "$start-$end of $totalRows";
        $return['querylimit'] = " LIMIT $min, $perPage";
        $return['next'] = $next;
        $return['prev'] = $prev;
        return $return;
    }
```